# "BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class" when deploying a JHipster monolithic app to Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, heroku, jhipster

I've never deployed any sort of JVM web app before so I really have no idea what's going on. From the Heroku log, the error looks to be the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [tld.domain.webapp.FinancialServicesStationApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration**
```

I am using MariaDB as my database, Gradle for building and the backend is written in kotlin. I used the option to compile the source code on my own machine, which I think should have worked since I can run the site in development mode just fine. Does someone know what could be causing this error and how I can fix it?

This is the full JHipster log:

```
2020-11-04T01:52:33.805989+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-04 01:52:33.801  INFO 4 --- [           main] .f.FinancialServicesStationApp$Companion : The following profiles are active: prod,heroku
2020-11-04T01:52:35.007983+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-04 01:52:35.007  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [tld.domain.webapp.FinancialServicesStationApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025845+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-04 01:52:35.025 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025847+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025849+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [tld.domain.webapp.FinancialServicesStationApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025850+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025851+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025852+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:811)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025853+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025854+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025854+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025856+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025856+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025857+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025857+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025858+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025858+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025859+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025859+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025860+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025861+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025862+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025863+00:00 app[web.1]: at tld.domain.webapp.FinancialServicesStationApp$Companion.main(FinancialServicesStationApp.kt:105)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025863+00:00 app[web.1]: at tld.domain.webapp.FinancialServicesStationApp.main(FinancialServicesStationApp.kt)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025863+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025864+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025864+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025865+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025865+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025866+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025866+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025866+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025867+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025867+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025868+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025868+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025877+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025878+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025878+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025879+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025879+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 26 common frames omitted
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025880+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'JDBC_DATABASE_URL' in value "${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}"
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025880+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025880+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025881+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025881+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025882+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:227)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025882+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:88)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025883+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025883+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:535)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025884+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:126)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025884+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025884+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 32 common frames omitted
2020-11-04T01:52:35.025885+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-04T01:52:35.104335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-04T01:52:35.142760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-04T01:55:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part of the error is:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'JDBC_DATABASE_URL' in value "${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}"
```

Heroku deployment could not inject the database properties into your application context and so it fails to start.

So, maybe you did not subscribe to jawsdb add-on or your did not register a payment method. There are few similar questions about this on stackoverflow

I suppose that you deployed using `jhipster heroku` as described in the doc: https://www.jhipster.tech/heroku/